# Unexpected identifier error, javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an unexpected identifier at `float farenheitFloat = parseFloat(farenheit)`

Can't for the life of me figure out why. Any help?

A little background...`validateFarenheit(farenheit)` is working.

```
function convertFarenheit() {
    var farenheit = document.getElementById('farenheit').value;
    if (validateFarenheit(farenheit)) {
        float farenheitFloat = parseFloat(farenheit);
        //float celsius = (farenheitFloat - 32) * (5/9);
        //float celsiusFormatted = parseFloat(Math.round(celsius * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        //alert(celsiusFormatted);  
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Should be `var` not `float`

Comment: as esalija said it should be `var farenHeitFloat = parseFloat(farenHeit)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

`float farenheitFloat = parseFloat(farenheit);`

There is no such thing as a `float` type (or any strict type declaration) in JavaScript.

Change it to:

`var farenheitFloat = parseFloat(farenheit);`

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, you always declare variables via

```
var myVariable;
```

You do not specify a type like `float`,but always say `var`.